# Help in evaluating conditional probabilities.

Tags: probability

I need some help in evaluating some probabilities.

My probability course is slightly too theoretical and abstract for me- we have been shown identities and theorems relating these probabilities but never were we shown an example or given any insight into how to actually evaluate them, perhaps I lack the assumed intuition but going purely off the definitions given to me I have no way that I'm aware of of actually doing the following (very simple) question.

Ideally some insight rather than a full solution to the below would be great- perhaps an outline or the first few lines or even a link to a similar question and a solution to that that I can apply here. But I'm aware that's a lot to ask so anything at all is appreciated.

> Parliament contains a proportion $p$ of Labour members, who are
>   incapable of changing their minds about anything, and a proportion
>   $1−p$ of Conservative members who change their minds completely at
>   random (with probability $r$) between successive votes on the same
>   issue. A randomly chosen member is noticed to have voted twice in
>   succession in the same way. What is the probability that this member
>   will vote in the same way next time?
>   So presumably we start with (say they have voted for $A$ so far)

$\mathbb P($will vote $A$ again$)=\mathbb P($will vote $A\space|\space$voted for $A$ twice$)=\mathbb P($will vote $A\space\cap$ voted for $A$ twice)$/\mathbb P($voted for $A$ twice$)$ but I don't know how to now evaluate these probabilities.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are finding the course too theoretical and abstract, perhaps you should try and understand the *process* rather than mechanically apply formulas.

I shall use assumed figures, I trust you can translate it into the formulas you have learned.

Labour MPs = 40, Conservative MPs = 60, who change their mind with $Pr = 0.4$

Number of Labour MPs voting A twice = 40,
Number of Conservative MPs voting twice $=60\times(1-0.4) = 36$

P(Labour |voted A twice) $=\dfrac{40}{76}$
P(Conservative | voted A twice) $=\dfrac{36}{76}$

P(will vote A again) $= \dfrac{40}{76}\cdot1 + \dfrac{36}{76}\cdot(1-0.4)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, this person is either one of those that are incapable of changing their minds, or it is one of the others that randomly change their minds.

A: will vote for A

C: can change their mind

R: repeated their vote for A

So:

$P(A|R) = P(A\land C|R) + P(A \land \neg C|R)$

where

$P(A\land C|R) = P(A|C,R)*P(C|R)$

$P(A\land \neg C|R) = P(A|\neg C,R)*P(\neg C|R)$

and where

$P(A|C,R)=1-r$  (the mind-changer will vote for A again with probability $1-r$)

and

$P(A|\neg C,R)=1$ (the mind-non-changer will certainly vote for A again)

and where (Bayesian rule):

$P(C|R) = \frac{P(R|C)*P(C)}{P(R)}$

where

$P(R) = P(R \land C) + P(R \land \neg C)$

$P(R \land C) = P(R|C) * P(C)$

$P(R \land \neg C) = P(R|\neg C) * P(\neg C)$

and

$P(R|C) = 1-r$

$P(R|\neg C) = 1$

$P(C) = 1-p$

$P(\neg C) = p$

(I'll leave the Bayesian for $P(\neg C|R)$ to you)